# Do I need separate servers for Mysql Dev and Live databases in order to optimize memory usage?

Tags: mysql, optimization, memory

My question is about mysql databases on same hardware / mysql instance and how it affects memory usage: INNODB_BUFFER_POOL more specific.

Today, we have all our DBs: Dev, BackUp and Live; residing on same rack/mysql server instance.

Would it be useful to build new server? Like Separate hardware and mysql instance to allocate better memory  for each needs (DEV,BackUp,Live)? Is there a way to allocate memory for each DB individually if they reside on same hardware / mysql instance?

Ex: DB1 can use max 64GB RAM, DB2 only max 16GB

I was thinking about building a standard server, for backup and Development, Testing. For the Live(production) server leave a better build ( memory, hardware) and leave it as dedicated as possible with only DB and tables needed.

Here some article I was reading as reference regarding what Im trying to explain.
 https://haydenjames.io/mysql-performance-drop-unused-databases/

Thanks

Comment: The separation of dev and production is more of a safety thing than a memory thing.

Comment: @ceejayoz My concern now is not about safety, only performance, for better use of our INNODB_BUFFER_POOL for the LIVE DB. We dont want to make concurrent usage of RAM memory and we do not wish backup db and dev db use too much of mysql server allocated memory.

Comment: One of the risks you take when you co-host dev and prod is that a silly mistake that wouldn't matter on a separate host (i.e. query using full table scan, `cross join` queries, experiments with configurations to resolve issues etc) can severely affect the production performance. Unfortunately, MySQL does not have great user segregation in terms of resources, unlike i.e. Oracle DB.

Comment: @Cascader. Thanks. I Might try separate server/instances or migrate to a new DB.

Comment: Maybe If i have some MyIsam Tables and InnoDB. INNODB_BUFFER_POOL allocates only to innodb tables right? So MyIsam wont hoard memory.

Comment: Is this a question of whether to use VMs or separate servers?  Or are you saying that the combined version is melting down, and need to expand?

Comment: You have a db and its backup on the same hardware and even same MySQL instance?  What is the backup protecting against; obviously not hardware failure?

Comment: Do not consider MyISAM.  Period.  Full stop.  End of discussion.